# How to call fragment which is in view pager from different Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have 3 pages which associated with activity and view pager. Now I have build it like my activity -> A-B-C fragment. In my activity I have called view pager adapter code for pager is given below:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{        
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    // Tab Titles
    private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            HomeFragment fragmenttab1 = new HomeFragment();
            return fragmenttab1;

            // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            CameraFragment fragmenttab2 = new CameraFragment();
            return fragmenttab2;

            // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FriendsFragment fragmenttab3 = new FriendsFragment();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

Now, I want to call c fragment from A but, it should be new instance of fragment, and also I want to call frag B from some of my activity... for that also how to start new instance of fragment.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fragment A create object of ViewPager and give it refrence of ViewPager which you use in your activity.

```
ViewPager  viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Then just call

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

In your case it will navigate you to FriendsFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of  FRAGMENT_POSITION and create instance like this

Add

```
//0 is for your first fragment , 1 for second and so on
    public final static int [] FRAGMENT_POSITION = {0, 1, 2};
```

in your adapter class, now to get an instance simply call

```
HomeFragment frag = (HomeFragment) mAdapter.getItem(FRAGMENT_POSITION[0]); //or 1 or 2
```

And for calling methods of a fragment from different activities pass instance of your adapter in that activity and do same as above

Comment: Sorry, i am new with Fragments, so if you can help me with how i am gone   keep track of Fragment position.. thx

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this before closing  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); this will direct your viewpager into that specific fragment when you open it